# Is a relational database well suited for vector calculations?

Tags: sql, optimization, math, vector

The basic table schema looks something like this (I'm using MySQL BTW):

`integer unsigned vector-id

integer unsigned fk-attribute-id

float attribute-value

primary key (vector-id,fk-attribute-id)`

The *vector* is represented as multiple records in the table with the same **vector-id**

I need to build a separate table with the dot product (also euclidean distance) of all vectors that exist in this table.  So, I need a result table that looks like this:

`integer unsigned fk-vector-id-a

integer unsigned fk-vector-id-b

float dot-product`


...and one like this...


`integer unsigned fk-vector-id-a

integer unsigned fk-vector-id-b

float euclidean-distance`

What is the best query structure to produce my result?

With very large vectors, is a relational database the best approach to solve this problem, or should I internalize the vectors in an application and do the calculation there?

Comment: Can different vectors have different dimensions? or can 2 vectors with same dimensionality have different sets of attributes ? i.e., can one have 3-D attributes { length, Width, Height}, and another have { weight, age, color }

Comment: cause obviously doing dot product requires that the 2 vectors be in the same N-Space, no ? i.e, dimensionality must be the same.

Comment: Yes, vectors are allowed to be different dimensions but only the overlap in attribute is included in the dot product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    dot_products
SELECT  v1.vector_id, v2.vector_id, SUM(v1.attribute_value * v2.attribute_value)
FROM    attributes v1
JOIN    attributes v2
ON      v2.attribute_id = v1.attribute_id
GROUP BY
        v1.vector_id, v2.vector_id
```

In `MySQL`, this can be faster:

```
INSERT
INTO    dot_products
SELECT  v1.vector_id, v2.vector_id,
        (
        SELECT  SUM(va1.attribute_value * va2.attribute_value)
        FROM    attributes va1
        JOIN    attributes va2
        ON      va2.attribute_id = va1.attribute_id
        WHERE   va1.vector_id = v1.vector_id
                AND va2.vector_id = v2.vector_id
        )
FROM    vector v1
CROSS JOIN
        vector v2
```

Comment: This will work but what are the performance characteristics of the query?  Will the JOIN take a year to complete on a large vector table?

Comment: `@JR Lawhorne`: if you have an index on `(atttribute_id, vector_id)`, it will most probably be faster than pulling the resultset into an application, building the new values and inserting them back.

Comment: I suggest adding `WHERE v1.vector_id < v2.vector_id` to avoid computing all dot products twice.